# Why is Locale Currency taking so long?

Tags: performance, currency, profiler

I have been profiling some pages and after clearing cache there is a really slow response from: `Locale/Currency`

I am not too sure why it is taking so long.
Here is the profiler entry:

[image: locale currency profiler]

Here is the time it takes:

[image]

Comment: Don't suppose you every figured this out and by any miracle remember what you did ?

Comment: No, unfortunately never managed to sort it.

Comment: on which file you change this?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution for this in the end. I think the slow speeds stems from loading each locale in full every time it needs to get some simple information about the store.

I created my own method since all i need is the currency, symbol and URL of the store. This made things significantly quicker.

```
public function getSpeedyCurrencyData()
{
    $data = array();
    $codes = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_ALLOW));

    foreach ($codes as $code) {
        $data[$code]['url'] = Mage::helper('directory/url')->getSwitchCurrencyUrl(array('currency' => $code));
        $symbol = Zend_Locale_Data::getContent('en_GB', 'currencysymbol', $code);

        if (!$symbol) {
            $symbol = $code;
        }

        $data[$code]['symbol'] = $symbol;
    }

    return $data;
}
```